# Transformation of $4-$velocity

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, vectors, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

Notation: a greek index indicates four labels; spacetime coordinates $\mu = (0,1,2,3)$. A latin index indicates three labels; spatial coordinates $i = (1,2,3)$.

$$* * *$$

A quantity, to be identified as a (contravariant) vectorial quantity, must satisfy the following rule (using Einstein's summation convention):

$$A'^{\mu} = \frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} A^{\nu} \tag{1}$$

So, the jacobian matrix in $(1)$ express the concept of invariance under any transformation rule. 
Now, consider, respectively, the 3-velocity and 4-velocity vector components:

$$v^{i} \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{i}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\tag{2}$$

$$u^{\mu} \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\tag{3}$$

where $\tau$ is the proper time.

Some books prefer to introduce the 4-velocity directly by differential geometry concepts saying that the 4-velocity is the vector tangent to the curve:

$$\alpha (\tau) = \alpha(t(\tau),x(\tau),y(\tau),z(\tau))$$

Others just say that the 4-velocity is a invariant quantity because we divide $\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$ by $\mathrm{d}\tau$ and it works because $d\tau = ds^{2}/c^{2}$ is a invariant quantity.

Now, a Minkowski vector is the quantity where the jacobian matrices are given by:

$$\frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} \equiv \Lambda^{\mu'}_{\nu} =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   \gamma & -\beta \gamma  & 0 & 0 \\
   -\beta \gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

(henceforth consider that the jacobian matrix are the lorentzian boost matrix).

In other words, a Minkowski vector is the one who transforms like:

$$A'^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu'}_{\nu} A^{\nu} \tag{4}$$

Then, after applying the tranformation $(4)$, in general a vectorial quantity in Minkowski spacetime (in cartesian coordinates) have the form:

\begin{cases}
A'^{0} = \gamma\Big(A^{0} - \frac{v}{c}A^{1} \Big) \\ A'^{1} = \gamma\Big(A^{1} - \frac{v}{c}A^{0} \Big)\\ A'^{2} = A'^{2}\\ A'^{3} = A'^{3}
\end{cases}
Well, here begin my confusion about 4-velocity. It's well known that if we simply try to generalize the 3-velocity to spacetime (to form 4-quantities) as:

$$v^{\mu} \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\tag{5} = \Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{2}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big)$$

won't work properly. But, if we take the quantity:

$$u^{\mu} \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{2}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\Big)\tag{6}$$

Then we can introduce a validy notion of velocity in spacetime physics.
Also, there is another technicality that is about the relationship between 4-velocity and 3-velocity.

$$u^{\mu} \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{2}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\Big) = \Big(\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t},\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t},\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{2}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t},\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big) \tag{7}$$

**Question:** So, my doubt is about the verificantion of Minkowskian vectorial character of $(7)$ and the non-vectorial character of $(5)$.
Because,there's a difference between the construction of 4-velocity (motivated by any argument that you want) and the verification as a true Minkowski vector.

I simply didn't get the right results. Firstly,I did applying the tranformation rule $(4)$ (which is the most general picture to treat about vectors! -At least to do the calculations of basic special/general relativity-)

$$u'^{\mu} \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{\mu}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}= \frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} \Big[\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big]  \equiv \frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} u^{\nu}\tag{8}$$

And I got the results:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \gamma\Big(\Big[\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big] - \frac{v}{c}\Big[\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big]\Big)
 =\gamma \Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}  - \frac{v}{c} \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\Big)$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \gamma\Big(\Big[\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big] -v\Big[\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big]\Big)
 =\gamma \Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}  -v\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\Big)$$

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{2}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{2}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} $$

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{3}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{3}(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau} $$

Which clear aren't in the form of a Minkowski vector.

On the other hand if we simply take the matrix product:

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
  \end{array} } \right]  = \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   \gamma & -\beta \gamma  & 0 & 0 \\
   -\beta \gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
  \end{array} } \right] $$

I got the right results:

$$\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma \Big[ \gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big] - \gamma \frac{v}{c}\Big[ \gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big]$$

$$\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma \Big[ \gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big] - \gamma \frac{v}{c}\Big[ \frac{\gamma\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big]$$

$$\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

$$\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Which is in the form of a Minkowskian vector.

Despite all of this, if I take the same matrix product using a the (wrong) attempt to 4-velocity given by $(5)$ I still get an Minkowskian vector:

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
  \end{array} } \right]  = \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   \gamma & -\beta \gamma  & 0 & 0 \\
   -\beta \gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
  \end{array} } \right] $$

I got a minkowskian vector form:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma \Big[\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big] - \gamma \frac{v}{c}\Big[\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big]$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma \Big[\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big] - \gamma \frac{v}{c}\Big[ \frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{0}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big]$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{1}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x'^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^{3}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

But this doesn't make much sense because this quantity are not a 4-velocity.

So, how can I verify that the 4-velocity transforms properly under a lorentz transformation and 3-velocity does not? (Using the formula $(4)$ ).

Comment: You already proofed $u^{\mu}$ being a Minkowski 4-vector in eq. (8) since  $u^{\mu}$ transforms like $A^{\mu}$ in eq. (4) (taking into account the definition of $\Lambda^{\mu}_\nu$ one line above). However, $v^{\mu}$ does not transform like a Minkowski 4-vector because $v'^\mu= \frac{dx^{\mu}}{dt'}$ (note the little prime) and depending on the reference system $dt =d\tau/\gamma$ or NOT. However in your equation it is simply assumed that $dt =d\tau/\gamma$ always. That's the point.  (On the other hand as you already said $d\tau$ is always the same independent on the reference system).

Comment: Equation (1) is missing a prime on the left hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**SECTION A : The 3+1-Lorentz transformation in the Standard Configuration**

I'll try to answer your questions and moreover in the more general 3+1 case.

So, let an inertial system $\:\mathrm S'\:$ translated with respect to the inertial system $\:\mathrm S\:$ with constant velocity
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathrm u_1,\mathrm u_2,\mathrm u_3\right)  \,, \qquad \Vert \mathbf{u}\Vert \boldsymbol{=} \mathrm u \in \left(0,c\right)
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
as shown in Figure-01.

The 3+1-Lorentz transformation is
\begin{align}                 
    \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}  \mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{+} \dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathbf{x}\right)\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}\mathbf{u}}{c}c\,t
\tag{02a}\label{02a}\\
 c\,t^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}   \gamma_{\mathrm u}\left(c\,t\boldsymbol{-} \dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{x}}{c}\right)
\tag{02b}\label{02b}\\
\gamma_{\mathrm u} & \boldsymbol{=} \left(1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathrm u^2}{c^2}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}\frac12}
\tag{02c}\label{02c} 
\end{align}
in differential form
\begin{align}                 
    \mathrm d\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}  \mathrm d\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)} \left(\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathrm d\mathbf{x}\right)\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}\mathbf{u}}{c}c\,\mathrm dt
\tag{03a}\label{03a}\\
c\, \mathrm dt^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}   \gamma_{\mathrm u}\left(c\,\mathrm dt\boldsymbol{-} \dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathrm d\mathbf{x}}{c}\right)
\tag{03b}\label{03b}      
\end{align}
and in matrix form
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} \boldsymbol{=} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
c t^{\boldsymbol{\prime}}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
 \boldsymbol{=} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm I\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)} \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}  & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}}{c}\mathbf{u} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}}{c}\mathbf{u}^{\boldsymbol{\top}} & \hphantom{-}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
c t\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=} \mathrm L\mathbf{X} 
\tag{04}\label{04}
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathrm L\:$ the real symmetric $\:4\times 4\:$ matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathrm L  \boldsymbol{\equiv}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm I\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)} \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}  & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}}{c}\mathbf{u} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}}{c}\mathbf{u}^{\boldsymbol{\top}} & \hphantom{-}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{05}\label{05}
\end{equation}

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!$

**SECTION B : Transformation of the velocities 3-vectors**

Suppose now that a point particle $\:\mathrm P\:$ is moving at a given instant $\:t\:$ with velocity $\:\mathbf w\:$ with respect to system $\:\mathrm S$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w} \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x}{\mathrm dt} \qquad (\text{velocity of point particle $\:\mathrm P\:$ with respect to system $\:\mathrm S\:$})  
\tag{06}\label{06}
\end{equation}
For its velocity $\:\mathbf w'\:$ with respect to system $\:\mathrm S'\:$ 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w'} \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x'}{\mathrm dt'} \qquad (\text{velocity of point particle $\:\mathrm P\:$ with respect to system $\:\mathrm S'\:$})
\tag{07}\label{07}
\end{equation}
we simply divide equations \eqref{03a} and \eqref{03b} side by side and so we find that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w'} \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathbf{w}\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}\left(\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{w}\right)}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{-}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\mathbf{u}}{\gamma_{\mathrm u}\left(1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{w}}{c^2}\right)}
\tag{08}\label{08}
\end{equation}
Above equation, beyond to be the transformation law for 3-velocities, is the law of relativistic addition of 3-velocities, more exactly of $\:\mathbf w\:$ and $\:\boldsymbol{-}\mathbf u \:$. If these two velocities $\:\mathbf w,\mathbf u\:$ are collinear with magnitudes $\:\mathrm w,\mathrm u\:$ respectively then equation \eqref{08} gives the known one-dimensional result
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{w'} \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathrm{w}\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm{u}}{1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathrm{u}\mathrm{w}}{c^2}}
\tag{09}\label{09}
\end{equation}

Now, we agree that a 4-dimensional real vector
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A} \boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathbf a, \alpha\right) \qquad \mathbf a \in \mathbb{R}^3, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation}
is a 4-vector (or Minkowski vector in terms of the question) if it is Lorentz transformed as the  4-dimensional position vector  $\:\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathbf x, c\,t\right)\:$ in Minkowski space, that is according to \eqref{04}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} \boldsymbol{=} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\alpha^{\boldsymbol{\prime}}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
 \boldsymbol{=} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm I\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)} \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}  & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}}{c}\mathbf{u} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}}{c}\mathbf{u}^{\boldsymbol{\top}} & \hphantom{-}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\alpha\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=} \mathrm L\mathbf{A} 
\tag{11}\label{11}
\end{equation}
written explicitly as in equations \eqref{02a} and \eqref{02b}
\begin{align}                 
    \mathbf{a}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}  \mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{+} \dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathbf{a}\right)\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}\mathbf{u}}{c}\alpha
\tag{12a}\label{12a}\\
 \alpha^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}   \gamma_{\mathrm u}\left(\alpha\boldsymbol{-} \dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{a}}{c}\right)
\tag{12b}\label{12b}
\end{align}

The construction of a velocity 4-vector 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{W} \boldsymbol{=}\left[\boldsymbol \eta\left(\mathbf w\right), \xi\left(\mathbf w\right)\right] \qquad \boldsymbol \eta\left(\mathbf w\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3, \xi\left(\mathbf w\right) \in \mathbb{R}
\tag{13}\label{13}
\end{equation}
from the velocity 3-vector $\:\mathbf w\:$ according to the transformation \eqref{08} encounters two problems :

1. The velocity 3-vector $\:\mathbf w\:$ is not transformed as the position 3-vector $\:\mathbf x\:$ does, see equation \eqref{02a}, because of the denominator in the rhs of equation \eqref{08}. So in equation \eqref{13} $\:\boldsymbol\eta\left(\mathbf w\right)\ne\mathbf w$, that is the velocity 3-vector $\:\mathbf w\:$ could not be the $^{\prime\prime}$space$^{\prime\prime}$ part of  the velocity 4-vector $\:\mathbf W$.
2. The unknown vector function $\:\boldsymbol\eta\left(\mathbf w\right)\:$ must be determined and paired together with the unknown scalar function $\:\xi\left(\mathbf w\right)$, the $^{\prime\prime}$time$^{\prime\prime}$ part of  the velocity 4-vector $\:\mathbf W$.

These two problems are solved and the construction of an acceptable velocity 4-vector $\:\mathbf W\:$ is achieved through a relation between the $\gamma-$factors $\gamma_{\mathrm u},\gamma_{\mathrm w},\gamma_{\mathrm w'}\:$ as it will be discussed in the next **SECTION C**.

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!$

**SECTION C : A relation between the $\gamma-$factors $\gamma_{\mathrm u},\gamma_{\mathrm w},\gamma_{\mathrm w'}\:$**

Between the $\gamma-$factors $\gamma_{\mathrm u},\gamma_{\mathrm w},\gamma_{\mathrm w'}\:$ the following equation is valid

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\gamma_{\mathrm w'} \boldsymbol{=}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\gamma_{\mathrm w}\left(1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{w}}{c^2}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\:\:}
\tag{14}\label{14}
\end{equation}
This relation is proved as follows :

Let $\:\mathrm S^{\mathrm P}\:$ the rest system of the particle $\:\mathrm P$. In this system $\:\mathrm S^{\mathrm P}\:$ the time is the proper one $\:\tau$. The rest system  $\:\mathrm S^{\mathrm P}\:$ is moving with velocity $\:\mathbf w\:$ with respect to system $\:\mathrm S\:$ so according to the Lorentz transformation between  these systems we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\tau}\boldsymbol{=}\gamma_{\mathrm w}
\tag{15}\label{15}
\end{equation}
On the same step, since the rest system  $\:\mathrm S^{\mathrm P}\:$ is moving with velocity $\:\mathbf w'\:$ with respect to system $\:\mathrm S'\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm d\tau}\boldsymbol{=}\gamma_{\mathrm w'}
\tag{16}\label{16}
\end{equation}
On the other hand from the Lorentz transformation between the systems $\:\mathrm S\:$ and $\:\mathrm S'\:$ we have, see \eqref{03b}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm dt}\boldsymbol{=}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\left(1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{w}}{c^2}\right)
\tag{17}\label{17}
\end{equation} 
From equations \eqref{15},\eqref{16} and \eqref{17} the relation \eqref{14} is proved, that is
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{\mathrm w'}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm d\tau}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm dt}\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\tau}\boldsymbol{=}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\gamma_{\mathrm w}\left(1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{w}}{c^2}\right)
\tag{18}\label{18}
\end{equation}

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!$

**SECTION D : Construction of the velocity 4-vector $\:\mathbf W$**

The denominator of the rhs of equation \eqref{08} is from the relation \eqref{14}
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{\mathrm u}\left(1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{w}}{c^2}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm w'}}{\gamma_{\mathrm w}}
\tag{19}\label{19}
\end{equation}
Replacing this in equation \eqref{08}, moving the primed variables to the lhs and the unprimed ones to the rhs  we have the following equation \eqref{20a} while equation \eqref{14} multiplied by $c$ gives equation \eqref{20b}
\begin{align}                 
    \left[\gamma_{\mathrm w'}\mathbf{w'}\right] & \boldsymbol{=}  \left[\gamma_{\mathrm w}\mathbf{w}\right]\boldsymbol{+} \dfrac{\gamma^2_{\mathrm u}}{c^2 \left(\gamma_{\mathrm u}\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \left[\gamma_{\mathrm w}\mathbf{w}\right]\right)\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma_{\mathrm u}\mathbf{u}}{c}\left[\gamma_{\mathrm w}c\right]
\tag{20a}\label{20a}\\
  \left[\gamma_{\mathrm w'}c\right] &\boldsymbol{=}\gamma_{\mathrm u}\left(\left[\gamma_{\mathrm w}c\right]\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left[\gamma_{\mathrm w}\mathbf{w}\right]}{c^2}\right)
\tag{20b}\label{20b}
\end{align}

Comparing the pair of equations \eqref{20a},\eqref{20b} with that of equations \eqref{02a},\eqref{02b} we note that the variables $\:\gamma_{\mathrm w}\mathbf{w}\:$ and $\:\gamma_{\mathrm w}c\:$ are transformed as the variables $\:\mathbf{x}\:$ and $\:c\,t\:$ of the position 4-vector $\:\mathbf{X}$. This means that the 4-dimensional vector 
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\mathbf{W} \boldsymbol{\equiv}\left(\gamma_{\mathrm w}\mathbf w, \gamma_{\mathrm w}c\right)\boldsymbol{=}\gamma_{\mathrm w}\left(\mathbf w, c\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{a}{b}}}\:\:}  
\tag{21}\label{21}
\end{equation}
is a 4-vector, the constructed velocity 4-vector in Minkowski space.

Comment: how to get eq.(02a)?