# Why does four-momentum have the same transformation matrix as spacetime coordinates?

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, inertial-frames, covariance

I will outline my question in 1+1D for brevity. We can passively transform our coordinate system using a Lorentz boost; $\Lambda^{\bar{\nu}}_{\mu}x^{\mu}=x^{\bar{\nu}}$. I've seen that, by stipulating that the speed of light is the same to all observers, rather than time, we can describe this transformation using the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{ct} \\
\bar{x} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\beta\gamma \\
-\beta\gamma & \gamma\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
ct \\
x \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, what's not obvious to me is why transformations $\Lambda^{\bar{\nu}}_{\mu}p^{\mu}=p^{\bar{\nu}}$ have the same form.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{E} \\
\bar{p_{x}} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\beta\gamma \\
-\beta\gamma & \gamma\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
E \\
p_{x} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I understand that all four-vectors transform under Lorentz transformations. The part I don't understand is why the Lorentz matrix has the same form, even though we're transforming a different basis. Intuitively it doesn't make sense to me why energy and momentum are transforming as though they were spacetime coordinates.

Comment: In my answer here : [Transformation of  4− velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460934/transformation-of-4-velocity/470031#470031) you will see another  proof that 4-velocity is a Lorentz 4-vector under a Lorentz boost along an arbitrary direction.  Lengthy  but with useful relations (transformation of velocity 3-vectors, relations between $\gamma-$factors etc).

Answer (score 2):

four-momentum is literally the first (proper) time derivative of position, multiplied by mass, so it is a vector with the same transformation rule.

Comment: Yeh makes sense, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Matematically, it is only the derivative at both sides with respect to the invariant parameter $\tau$, and multiplication by another scalar invariant $m$. As the Lorentz matrix is a constant, that is, it doesn't depend on $\tau$, the first equation leads to the second one.

Comment: Yeh makes sense, cheers

Answer (score 1):

$p^\mu$ has to transform as $p^\mu \to \Lambda^\mu_{~~\nu}p^\nu$ if you want quantities like $$x^\mu p_\mu$$ to be lorentz invariant. For example if you want to measure the mass of a particle you might choose $$x^\mu = (1,\mathbf{0})$$ and $$p^\mu = (m,\mathbf{0}),$$ so$$x^\mu p_\mu = m$$ If this wasn't boost invariant then you'd measure a different mass for the particle in different frames.

Comment: Ah yes that adds to it too. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the earlier answers, one can form a scalar $S=(tE-\vec x\cdot \vec p)$ which has the units of action. Regarding this as the [Lorentz-metric] dot-product of two 4-vectors, this implies $(E,\vec p)$ also transforms a 4-vector.